# DevExpress and C# font changes

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, devexpress

I am trying to change the default font in a DevExpress utility within a C# program. Right now I'm using: DevExpress.Utils.AppearanceObject.DefaultFont = font;
However, this code is only changing the menu font on the form and it should change all of it. I've also tried enumerating through the controls on the form and changing the text as that was mentioned in a similar question, but that didn't work either. Hopefully someone knows how to do this with DevExpress...

Comment: Did you ask on DevEspresses support forum?

Comment: Well I was going to but I'm at work and can't register for it right now. Thought I'd try here since this is the only thing I have to work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call DevExpress.Utils.AppearanceObject.DefaultFont = YourFont before the InitializeComponents() or Application.Run.

```
static void Main() 
{
         DevExpress.Utils.AppearanceObject.DefaultFont = new Font(your font);
         Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```